# Guide an MPI Programmer to understand the Spark communication model

Tags: apache-spark, parallel-processing, mpi, cluster-computing, communication

My background is in scientific HPC and until my current job I worked mainly with MPI and CUDA. In these programming models, the individual algorithm that each core executes to solve the problem in question is sometimes less important than the meta-algorithm that governs internode communication. I understand these concepts in the context of problems like the diffusion equation, in which ensuring the cores communicate in a way that scales is arguably more important than the actual finite difference updates executed in between message passing phases.

Now I work big data for a big company as an engineer and am fairly fluent in spark. The problems I work on now involve joins, aggregations, and optimizing at a higher level of abstraction (partitions, shuffles, stages, tasks, memory management, etc).

Old habits die hard though and despite my interest, I have been unable to find consistent information regarding how spark handles all-to-all and scatter/gather type communications to perform shuffles.

What communications algorithms does spark use to perform these computations? Specifically:

- Shuffles in general

I understand what a shuffle IS and why it needs to happen, just not specifically how it goes down over the network. Or if it can be broken out by the following that would be even better:

- Joins (inner and outer)
- groupBy, a single key, or multiple keys
- Sorting
- Counting

On a higher level, I'd also like to know how synchronization is handled.

Thanks very much.

Comment: Good question.  It might be a better fit at http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com, but do check their Ts and Cs before re-posting.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark this question is a poor fit over there, see http://meta.softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/6483/why-was-my-question-closed-or-down-voted/6490#6490 Recommended reading: **[What goes on Software Engineering (previously known as Programmers)? A guide for Stack Overflow](http://meta.softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/7182/31260)**